# Missing data from boot logs

Tags: boot, logs

I'm having stability problems with my PC running Ubuntu 22.04.1. After hard reboot from frozen system state, I noticed a group of 50+ lines with messages about my SSDs including `nvme0` device name. I checked `boot.log`, `dmesg`, `syslog` and other new files in `/var/log` directory, and haven't found these messages. Where should I look for them?

Comment: You noticed 50+ lines, but _where did you see them?_  Knowing where you saw them is the first clue about which logfile might have them preserved.

Comment: if you're using `systemd` (which is the default on most linux distros these days): have you tried running `journalctl -k`?   Also, if you're worried about your drives, you should probably install smartmontools and run `smartctl` to query the drives and run tests.

Comment: @SottoVoce When Linux boots you can see the terminal with messages printed to it, before GUI login prompt appears.

Comment: @cas Thank you. I looked at the logs with `systemd` and I can't find these messages there. `smartctl` was always showing no SSDs errors.

Comment: journalctl journalctl journalctl

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov My bad, I meant `journalctl --dmesg --boot=-2`. I checked a few recent boots.

Comment: Messages sent to the console from power-on until the syslog service is launched are kept in a buffer that the `dmesg` command reads.  Many distros also send those lines to a logfile in /var/log, but I've seen cases where this logfile doesn't have the earliest messages in the buffer.  I suggest invoking the `dmesg` command as root immediately after you boot and log in, and redirect the output to a file to preserve it.  It might have the items you're looking for.